# How to call Oracle stored procedure with c#

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

I have the below stored procedure which I want to call from a c# app:

```
PROCEDURE   WS_GetTransDetails_199 (TransID IN NUMBER, MsgData_RESPONSE OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ) IS
 v_busdate date;
begin 
    select last_run_date  into v_busdate from psdev.fpatch_operations where load_type=1 and patch_id=24  order by patch_id,seq_no;
        
        OPEN MsgData_RESPONSE for
        SELECT   DATE_32A,CURRENCY_32A,AMOUNT_32A,nvl(CURRENCY_33B,CURRENCY_32A),AMOUNT_33B,TRANS_FLAG,nvl(REJECTED_REASONE,10),nvl(COMM_AMT,0)
         FROM psdev.FMESTYP_SWIFTINWARD
         WHERE "ID"=TransID
         and MTYPE=103 
        --AND ReadFlag=1  
         AND ResponseCode=0 --and busdate is not null  ---=busdate=v_busdate 
         ORDER BY   BUSDATE,USRNO,OPRNO ;          
END WS_GetTransDetails_199;
```

I am getting this execption:

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 8
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'WS_GETTRANSDETAILS_199' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

```cs
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
HostCon = new OracleConnection(this._OracledbConnectionString);
cmd.Connection = HostCon;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "WS_GetTransDetails_199";
cmd.Parameters.Add("TransID", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = ID;
cmd.Parameters.Add("MsgData_RESPONSE", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
if (HostCon.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    HostCon.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
```